# React Natice Expo: How can I change 「BottomTab.Screen」name type alias to Japanese?

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, react-navigation, react-typescript

Background
I try first time React Native Expo with typescript.
so, I have no idea to use `BottomTab.Screen`.

Q. I would like to change `「name="TabOne"」` to Japanese is `「ホーム」`.

```
// navigation/BottomTabNavigator.tsx
const BottomTab = createBottomTabNavigator<BottomTabParamList>();

export default function BottomTabNavigator() {
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();

  return (
    <BottomTab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="TabOne"
      tabBarOptions={{ activeTintColor: Colors[colorScheme].tint }}>
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="TabOne" // ホーム
        component={TabOneNavigator}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => <TabBarIcon name="home" color={color} />,
        }}
      />
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="TabTwo"// タスク
        component={TabTwoNavigator}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => <TabBarIcon name="task" color={color} />,
        }}
      />

    </BottomTab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

```js
// types.tx
export type BottomTabParamList = {
  TabOne: undefined;
  TabTwo: undefined;
};
```

※ memo
This project is React Native Expo with TypeSript.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `title` or `tabBarLabel` to specify a title:

```js
const BottomTab = createBottomTabNavigator<BottomTabParamList>();

export default function BottomTabNavigator() {
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();

  return (
    <BottomTab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="TabOne"
      tabBarOptions={{ activeTintColor: Colors[colorScheme].tint }}>
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="TabOne"
        component={TabOneNavigator}
        options={{
          title: 'ホーム',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => <TabBarIcon name="home" color={color} />,
        }}
      />
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="TabTwo"
        component={TabTwoNavigator}
        options={{
          title: 'タスク',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => <TabBarIcon name="task" color={color} />,
        }}
      />

    </BottomTab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#tabbarlabel

Comment: Thank you for letting me know.

With this, all the problem is resolved.

I appreciate you kind explanation.